# MySQL not using tmpdir path with tmpfs

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set MySQL's tmpdir however it never uses the location I've set and fills the following location instead -

```
/dev/mapper/kaboobie--lvm-root  9.2G  1.5G  7.3G  17% /
```

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir = /dev/shm
```

**df -h**

```
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                           6.3G   30M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/kaboobie--lvm-root  9.2G  1.5G  7.3G  17% /
/dev/mapper/kaboobie--lvm-usr    46G  1.6G   42G   4% /usr
tmpfs                            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                       917G  632G  240G  73% /data
/dev/mapper/kaboobie--lvm-var    46G 1019M   43G   3% /var
/dev/sda1                       922M   63M  796M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/kaboobie--lvm-home   46G  364M   43G   1% /home
tmpfs                           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

**mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';**

```
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| tmpdir        | /dev/shm/ |
+---------------+-----------+
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried to restart mysql and give write permissions to /whatever/directory/you/want for mysql user?

Comment: @Mukyuu - yup restarted MySQL, no errors and permissions are good.